# Open application/hal+json response inline in browser instead of downloading it

Tags: google-chrome, download, inline, hal-json

I would like to open "application/hal+json" response inline in my Chrome browser. The problem is that the Chrome browser doesn't recognize the HAL response and downloads it. Before I always used [the JSON view extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) for checking my JSON response. But since swapping to HAL it immediately downloads my response so I cannot review it anymore.

Comment: You can participate on resolving the issue for JSONView: https://github.com/bhollis/jsonview/issues/7

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**For Chrome:**
I just ran into a nice solution myself. I hope answering here will help some other people who run into the same problem... 
Installing this ['application/...+json|+xml as inline'](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cgfnklamhhieaepdicnbahkbnolpbdmp) chrome extension solved it nicely. I am now able to review my server response again as normal.

---

**For FireFox:**
Install the extension called [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/jsonview/). After install go to extensions page (default: `ctrl`+`shift`+`a`) find the JSONView extension and go to options. There you can add *"Alternate JSON content types"* that should be opened as by the extension. Simply add `application/hal+json` to the input field and it will work:

[image]

---

**REST developer add-ons:** Another solution can be to install a REST developer add-on. The advantage is that you can also change the http request verb (POST, GET, PATCH, PUT, DELETE) and custom set your request headers. A great REST plugin for Chrome is [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) and a nice one for FireFox is [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/restclient/). But there are several other ones available.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for Firefox?

Comment: Also, I'm not so sure this even does anything. Chrome is downloading a file when I select the "preview" tab with application/hal+json, this plugin doesn't rectify that for me.

Comment: **FOR FIREFOX** @acohen it's probably too late, but for someone who looking for answer, here's solution: download extension [JSONView](http://jsonview.com/), after install go to extensions page (default: ctrl+shift+a) find on list JSONView and go to options of this extension. And under rates and reviews there is option "Include "application/json" in the HTTP Accept header for request." **enable it**. After this I can open app/json in firefox ;)

Comment: @mij, thanks for your answer. I changed it a bit and added it. There is an *"Alternate JSON content types"* field as well in the options panel you mentioned. This seems better since it will not change any of your outgoing requests.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but installing the [HAL Browser](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal-browser) from your web server will convert HAL to HTML for viewing your application/hal+json responses inline. It's particularly nice because it makes the links navigable and also links to the relation documentation (if the relation name is a URI).

Oddly enough, my Chrome sends an Accept header of */*;q=0.8 so it falls back to anything the server sends it. I wonder if you're running a different version of Chrome than I am. I'm on v30.0.1599.101.

Comment: Can you point to some useful link/resources which can guide for how to install HAL browser ? Thanks

Comment: The code is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal-browser). The README explains how to install: drop the files into the root directory (or a subdirectory) of your web server.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I did exactly the same way, copy pasted every files and directory to webapps.. but still no luck..

Answer (score 1):

Came here looking for a solution for Firefox and `application/hal+json` content type.

I ended up installing [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/jsonview/), which has an option in its preferences menu to add extra content types.